# Binding FANN with python mac os

Tags: python, macos, fann

I try binding FANN with my python in mac os.
I have next steps:
1.Download FANN 2.2
2. Install it as usual.

```
  ./configure
  make
  sudo make install
```

2. install last XCODE
3. Download source code FANN for binding.
3. then i try:

```
python setup.py install
```

4. i have problem:

```
unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
```

5. i solved this problem, i try

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

and this work.

6.then i try again `python setup.py install`

after i have new error:

```
ld: library not found for -ldoublefann

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error: command 'g++-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

what's wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
Just use this guide - http://witzawitz.com/2012/11/installing-fann-on-macosx-10-7-with-python-binding/

After setup create folder "nets" fann-2.1.0/python/examples/ for correct use examples files.